# Marshmallow - iBeacon fine location battery drain

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, ibeacon-android

We are working on an app that needs to scan for iBeacons in background. We did a lot of optimizations and now it works well on Kitkat and Lollipop devices without consuming much battery.

On Marshmallow we require fine location permission to scan for iBeacons (coarse location has delays). This drains a lot of battery even if we have the same battery saving logic in place.

Is there a way that we can release fine location permission when the device is still (no movement) and acquire it when we see a movement? Since the user would have provided the runtime permission at app launch, re-acquiring that permission shouldn't bring the permission dialog again.

If there is way to achieve this, it would help us save the battery drain problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Scanning for BLE devices requires either `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  It doesn't matter which one an app obtains.
- In my tests, there is no difference in BLE device scanning performance between either of the above permissions.  For this reason, the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) documentation suggests requesting `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, and declares this permission in its manifest.
- Declaring, requesting or obtaining a permission has no affect on battery drain.  It is actually doing location-specific operations (BLE scanning, requesting GPS location updates, etc.) that affects battery usage.

The description of the problem says the app uses more battery when `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is obtained vs. `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.  Because of the points above, I do not believe the difference is explained beacon scanning.  A possible alternative explanation is that the app is requesting location updates from the operating system (since I can't see the code, I don't know if this is true -- it's just a theory).  If `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is obtained, then that will unlock the `GPS_PROVIDER`, potentially powering up the GPS and causing the additional battery drain described.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

> Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I was also under impression that requesting or obtaining a permission would not drain battery unless we use that feature. Unfortunately, using Fine Location drains more battery than Coarse Location even if our app is not using GPS. Coarse location has acceptable battery drain but the response is slow. It takes 3-5 seconds to detect a beacon even with 1 second scanning and low latency mode. Our use case requires faster response.